# Django REST - rest_auth custom fields not being serialized

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I'm using Django REST with the rest_auth package, and I'm having an issue with serializing custom fields when registering a new user.

The field "is_employer" is always set to false even when you set it to true. Also in the API if you set the is_employer checkbox to true, it doesn't change anything. I added it in models, serializers and adapter, what am I missing?

[image]

MODELS:

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = None
    first_name = None
    last_name = None
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email address', max_length=255, unique=True)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    is_employer = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = MyUserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(selfself, app_label):
        return True;
```

SERIALIZERS:

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_auth.registration.serializers import RegisterSerializer
from users.models import CustomUser

class CustomRegisterSerializer(RegisterSerializer):
        def get_cleaned_data(self):
            data_dict = super().get_cleaned_data()
            data_dict['is_employer'] = self.validated_data.get('is_employer', '')
            return data_dict
```

ADAPTER:

```
class CustomAccountAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def save_user(self, request, user, form, commit=False):
        user = super().save_user(request, user, form, commit)
        data = form.cleaned_data
        user.is_employer = data.get('is_employer')
        user.save()
        return user
```

Comment: Anyone? I'm stuck.. Please let me know how I can improve the question.

Comment: did you set any settings variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, set the **`is_employer`** field explicitly in the **`CustomRegisterSerializer`** class

```
from rest_auth.registration.serializers import RegisterSerializer


class CustomRegisterSerializer(RegisterSerializer):
    is_employer = serializers.BooleanField(default=True)

    def get_cleaned_data(self):
        data_dict = super().get_cleaned_data()
        data_dict['is_employer'] = self.validated_data.get('is_employer', False)
        return data_dict
```

then in your `settings.py` update the serializer as

```
# settings.py
REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
    "REGISTER_SERIALIZER": "dotted.path.to.CustomRegisterSerializer"
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfectly. Remind me to award my bounty if I forget (available in 2 hours)

Comment: Regarding the NOTE you added, I tried removing the line "user.is_employer = data.get('is_employer')" but then it wouldn't work anymore :) just fyi. Unless that's not what you meant.

Comment: Removed the note :)